# Composer 2.0 Problems

Tags: php, laravel, package, composer-php, version

Recently i attempted to install a package on a project i work on via Composer. Upon installing i was prompted a message that Composer 2.0 is released and asked me if i want to update it. Normally it seemed like a stable release but upon update the package wasnt installed and this error poped up.

```
composer require spatie/laravel-tags
Using version ^3.0 for spatie/laravel-tags
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update spatie/laravel-tags
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework 8.0, found laravel/framework[v8.0.0] but the package is fixed to v7.30.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
  Problem 2
- spatie/laravel-tags[3.0.0, ..., 3.0.1] require laravel/framework ^8.0 -> found laravel/framework[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but the package is fixed to v7.30.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- Root composer.json requires spatie/laravel-tags ^3.0 -> satisfiable by spatie/laravel-tags[3.0.0, 3.0.1].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Anyone experienced this issue or have any guidelines how can i fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Please share more details - the given problem does not look related to Composer v2 to me, but to `laravel/framework`  being installed in v7.30.0 (as the error message tells you)

Comment: @NicoHaase yes my bad... it wasnt related to composer v2 ... there was a missmatch with the versions in the composer dependencies. I answered below what solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved this by running composer outdated -D first and the manually update the versions of laravel/framework in composer.json and then ran composer update.